# How to find the largest difference in height between two lines on a graph? (one is non-linear)

Tags: calculus

The functions I've used as an example is $y=20x$ and $y=5x^3$. Constraints: $y\leq 40$, $0\leq x \leq5$.

Thanks for any help...Don't know a good tag, this is...algebra...and graphs...so algebraic-geometry...?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know calculus?

Comment: I have an A-level in Maths but haven't done it in a while...I really don't know what to do, tried differentiating the equations...but i don't know where that leads to...

Comment: I don't understand the question It sounds almost like you want to maximize $|20x-5x^3|$ over $0\leq x\leq 5$, but then the constraint $y\leq 40$ doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could approach it is using calculus. You've got two functions $f(x)=20x$, and $g(x)=5x^3$, we can define a new function (the height function which we will call $h$) by $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)=5x^3-20x$. This tells us the vertical distance between the two lines you're considering. Now whenever $\lvert h(x)\rvert$ is maximized, we know that the vertical distance between the two functions is maximized.

Now, we know from elementary calculus, that a function will maximize at critical it's critical points -- these occur when the derivative of your function is zero or we are at an end point of our interval (in this case $x=0$ or $x=5$).
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}h(x)=15x^2-20
$$
So when is this going to be equal to zero?
$$
15x^2-20=0 \implies  x = \pm\sqrt{\frac{20}{15}}\approx \pm 1.1547
$$
Since we are only interested in values of $x$ that range from $0$ to $5$ we can get rid of the $-\sqrt{\frac{20}{15}}$ option. Now you have three values to check:

$\lvert h(0)\rvert$, $\left\lvert h\left(\sqrt{\frac{20}{15}}\right)\right\rvert$, and $\lvert h(5)\rvert$.

Which one of those is largest? Does it fit within your range of allowable $y$ values? How could you restrict the original interval so that your $y$ values stay within the appropriate bounds?

Comment: Thank you, I was along the right lines...

Comment: The allowable range of $x$ is only from $0$ to $2$ because $y(2)=40$ for both graphs.

Answer (score 1):

The vertical distance between them is the absolute difference of the $y$ values, so is $|20x-5x^3|$  Take the derivative of this (the absolute value bars don't matter because you just have to subtract them in the right order), set the derivative to $0$ and solve the resulting equation.  That will give you a candidate point.  You also have to check the end points of the interval.  Note that the restriction on $y$ reduces the allowable range of $x$ values.